# From Windows Forms to WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

I am a long time experienced **Windows Forms** developer, but now it's time to move to **WPF** because a new WPF project is comming soon to me and I have only a short lead time to prepare myself to learn WPF.

What is the best way for a experienced Winforms devleoper?

Can you give me some hints and recommendations to learn **WPF** in a very short time!

Are there simple sample WPF **solutions** and short (video) **tutorials**? Which books do you recommend? Is [www.windowsclient.net](http://www.windowsclient.net) a good starting point? Are there alternatives to the official Microsoft site?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Better post this in programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: **Your** use of **bolds** is **very** interesting.

Comment: @Gunner:  Why do you think it belongs to programmers.se?  It doesn't look like a good question there.  Vote to close if you like, but don't migrate to p.se.

Comment: @David Thornley: Well the matter looked to be a bit more subjective. Now that I look into it again, it's ok for this site. And I sure will not vote to close this, cause I was planning to ask this question myself on programmers.stackexchange.com :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like this tutorial:

http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/

Also, dont be afraid about forgeting what you learned. WPF was designed as totaly different technology than WinForms. So in some aspects it results in completly different techniques to reach your goal.

Comment: I for one am very grateful that WPF gives me the opportunity to forget certain things that I've learned about Windows Forms development.

Answer (score 2):

A really well done book is [http://www.amazon.com/WPF-4-Unleashed-ebook/dp/B003UBAYXE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003UBAYXE)

Comment: It's the best book available for WPF.  It also doesn't cover data binding until chapter 9 and is silent on MVVM.  It took me months to learn to use WPF effectively because I relied on this book too much.  Get this, and read it, but you must look elsewhere too.

Answer (score 1):

There has been much debate on [Charles Petzold's book "Applications = code + markup"](http://www.charlespetzold.com/wpf/) but I still value it.